# How to specify and use a locally installed package in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, armadillo

I'm trying make a program which requires Armadillo as a dependency. I've installed Armadillo in a local directory (I'm working on a cluster without root privileges), but am unable to install the program because it can't find armadillo. How would I specify that? Thanks in advance for the help!

**What I'm doing & seeing:**

```
$ make
g++     -O3 -o ancestry_hmm ancestry_hmm.cpp -larmadillo
ancestry_hmm.cpp:22:21: fatal error: armadillo: No such file or directory
 #include <armadillo>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

**The current Make file:**

```
TCFLAGS = -ltcmalloc
ARMAFLAGS = -larmadillo

all:
        $(LINK.cc) -O3 -o ancestry_hmm ancestry_hmm.cpp $(ARMAFLAGS)
```

**Path to armadillo:**
`/{user}/Programs/Anaconda/*.so`
`/{user}/Programs/Anaconda/`

Comment: Use `g++ -O3 -o ancestry_hmm ancestry_hmm.cpp -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -I<your ARMA dir>  -lblas -llapack`

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by Claes Rolen in the comments. I had to also add -lgfortran, but it works, thanks!